# how to select particular column data in SQLite db in android studio?

Tags: sqlite, android-studio

I want to take data from table name "transactions" in my SQLite db and return it to main activity in android studio.

This is my DatabaseHelper.java class code to return balance from transactions table:

```
public int previousBal(String activeuser){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select balance from transactions where email=? order by t_id desc limit 1",new String[]{activeuser});
        int balance = cursor.getInt(Integer.parseInt("balance"));
        return balance;

    }
```

This is the MainActivity code. I am using previousBal method to get data from the table:

```
String bal;
int previousBal=db.previousBal(activeuser);
bal= String.valueOf(previousBal);
System.out.println("PREVIOUS BALANCE IS======"+bal);
```

This code does not return anything. help me figure it out.

Comment: Change ur query to "select balance from transactions". Do you get any result? Just trying to make sure your filter is okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have, assuming that the active user string is a valid exisitng  user, is that you are trying to extract from the position that is effectively before the first row.

That is, you need to MOVE to a row in the Cursor.

Additionally the Cursor's `getInt` method expects the offset of the column from which to get the data, which would be 0. However, it is better (less prone to error and generally more flexible) to use the Cursor's `getColumnIndex` method to retrieve the column's offset.

As such change :-

```
    public int previousBal(String activeuser){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select balance from transactions where email=? order by t_id desc limit 1",new String[]{activeuser});
        int balance = cursor.getInt(Integer.parseInt("balance"));
        return balance;

    }
```

to :-

```
    public int previousBal(String activeuser){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select balance from transactions where email=? order by t_id desc limit 1",new String[]{activeuser});
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int balance = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("balance"));
        } else {
            balance = 0;
        }
        return balance;

    }
```

- This will move to the first row, if there is one, and extract the vale in the balance column of the cursor.
- If there is no row that matches the query's selection criteria then the `else` clause will set the balance to 0.

  - If multiple rows are extracted the value from the first row will be returned.

#### Addtional

Frequently the use of the SQLiteDatabase `rawQuery` is frowned upon unless it is necessary. In you case the SQLitedatabase `query` method can be used. As such, the recommended `previousBal` method would be :-

```
    public int previousBal(String activeuser){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor.query(
            "transactions",               // name of the table to query
            new String[]{"balanace"},     // String array of columns to extract
            "email=?",                    // WHERE clause (? indicates an arg)
            new String[]{activeuser},     // The list of args to replace the ? (or ?'s on a sequential basis)
            null,                         // GROUP BY clause
            null,                         // HAVING clause
            "t_id DESC",                  // ORDER clause
            "1"                           // LIMIT value as a String
        );
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int balance = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("balance"));
        } else {
            balance = 0;
        }
        return balance;   
    }
```

- The query convenience method builds the SQL escaping characters and offers improved protection against SQL injection.

Comment: Your method works perfectly, just needed one minor change-cursor.moveToFirst to cursor.moveToFirst().... thankyou@MikeT

Comment: That's good, yep I didn't actually test the code as I ran out of time (normally I add a disclaimer when I haven't tested it)

Comment: @PranitDarekar PS amended the answer to correct my mistake.